# How to place two DOM elements on the same line

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to put on the same line `$('.prize-item input')` and `$('.prize-edit')`

Here is the DOM structure (1) and the CSS code (2).

I tried to sue the `display:inline-block` with no success.

The prerequisite is the following:
1) You must not use position absolute.
2) Resizing the screen, the distance between the button and the input box should not change.
3) The DOM structure should be changed only if it is not possible to obtain the result I requested with CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jBme9/8/

---

(1)

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="prize-edit">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="">Edit Same line</button>
        </div>
        <div class="prize-item">
            <div class="control-group ">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="form-prize-item-name" value="prize same line">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> 
</div>
```

### ​

(2)

```
.prize-edit {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.prize-item input {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: you need a button in your input box?

Comment: Hi @Mr.Alien, Not exactly. I would like to have the edit button on the right of the input not inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relative positioning. Please adjust these values for your real page.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/sUvAC/)

Code:

```
.controls button {
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    top:38px;
    right:17px;
}
```

I used pixels 'cause you're using pixels, but this can be done with `em`s too.

---

To push the `button` outside the `input`, add another class to the input's wrapper. Let's call it "controlsWrapper".

So that you'll have in html:

```
<div class="controls controlsWrapper"><input...other stuff...></div>
```

And in CSS

```
.controls button {
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    top:38px;
}
.controlsWrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    padding-right:40px; /* width of the button + some space */
}
```

[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/J738k/)

Comment: +1 Hi, your solution is fine. Actually I would like to have the button on the right of the input box not inside. any ideas?

Comment: This is a better solution for sure... +1

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Alien, i thought about % on input too, but that cause issue on different screen sizes...

Comment: @GionaF I tried the same but this is something good, I made % about 80..and than floated the input box towards left

Answer (score 0):

I think it´s not possible with this DOM structure. You want to have something like this:

```
<div class="aWrapper">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="prize-edit">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="">Edit Same line</button>
      </div>
      <div class="prize-input"><!-- I renamed the class! -->
                <input type="text" class="form-prize-item-name" value="prize same line">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

additional:

```
.label { diplay: block; }
.prize-edit { float: right; width: 20%; // adjust with paddings etc. }
.prize-input { float: left; width: 80% // adjust ... }
```